# Twohanded enemies one shot me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have encountered a rather odd and annoying "feature" in Skyrim. It seems like enemies wielding twohanded weapons have no trouble killing me in one or two strikes, regardless of wether I block or not. My level is 20 and have been focusing on a standard sword and board warrior type. I'm wearing Steelplate armor and using the Mace of Molag Bal. Other enemies are a walk in the park, even dragons. But twohanders really give me trouble. I'm currently playing on Expert but am considering lowering it to Adept just for this one fight I have with a bandit chief.

Any one else have this experience with twohanders?

Comment: Rumor: there is a bug with killcam moves, which ignores armor.  Step 1, attack connects.  Step 2, does raw damage kill you?  If Yes, start kill cam.  Step 3, apply armor to damage (doesn't matter, you're dead).

Comment: I see that you are wearing steel plate armor, but you don't say how much armor you have.  What is your armor count?  In what armor perks have you invested?  This is something that you might be able to remedy by wearing better armor, since steel is pretty low in the hierarchy of heavy armor types.  Also, have you improved your armor at a blacksmith's table?  Anything you can do to increase your armor or its effectiveness should be beneficial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have seen people mention this a few times and question if the game is broken.

Its basically that the game is meant to be challenging. **A power strike from a two handed weapon does considerable damage to a player** and is not something you can normally block. When you see an enemy winding up you pretty much need to get out of the way in one way or another. Your options, as I recall, are along the lines of:

- Do something to disrupt their attack

  - A shield bash
  - a shout that can disrupt actions
- Get out of the way
- Raise your HP enough to where you can withstand a large two handed attack.

You can lower the difficulty, that will make enemies do less damage so by its very nature you are effectively doing what is last on the list up there just inversely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see the logic in one way, but I still don't think it should do THAT much damage. Also, the game has no real dodge move which makes combat sometimes feel unrefined. Blocking is really only the true defensive combat move you can make. Still going to +1 and accept your answer.

Comment: @Sandokan I usually play a dagger wielder and I can pull off my power moves pretty fast to usually disrupt a two handed power strike. It just becomes a lesson you start to pick up quickly... or get frustrated with game, hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as a Sword and Board character you're pretty much going to want to shield bash him the moment you see him winding up a power attack. If you can time it so your bash hits him just before his weapon hits you, it creates a larger stagger effect, allowing for more strikes before he recovers.

Another option, there is a perk in the Block skill tree, "Quick Reflexes," that slows time whenever you're blocking during an enemy power attack; this perk is AMAZING. Most enemies will power attack around 40-50% of the time, allowing for you to activate this perk, CONSTANTLY. It slows time so much, that you can move out of the way of their attack, all the way behind them, getting in 2-3 hits in the process.

A 3rd option would simply be to stagger lock him. Simply spamming shield bash in between your attacks should prevent him from doing much of anything, all the while you can chip away at his health. However, this requires quite a bit of Stamina/Stamina regen. to work properly.

Hopefully you'll have luck with 1 of these 3 styles my friend. C;

Comment: Well the thing is, I don't even get time to do this. He swings his 2-hander just as fast as a 1-hander. I simply run out of stamina and health WAY before I kill him. All I can do is trying to block or run. Don't even get an opening for a counter attack.